# Route alias, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Vehicle model:

**Routes:**

```
map.resources :vehicles, :has_many => :suppliers
```

Everything works great, but Vehicle has a boolean attribute **is_truck**. I want to make an Alias so I can get the same resources filtering only trucks, I tried with:

**Routes:**

```
map.trucks '/trucks', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true
map.trucks '/trucks/by_supplier/:supplier', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true
```

The first one works well, but when I search within a Form the second doesn't work and searches all suppliers.

**Controller:**

```
class VehiclesController
   def index
     if params[:supplier]
       @vehicles = Vehicle.all :conditions => { :is_truck => params[:is_truck] }
     else
       @vehicles = Vehicle.all
     end
   end
   ...
end
```

**Search Form:**

```
<% form_for :truck, :url => {:controller => :trucks, :action => :index}, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :search %>
  <% f.submit 'Search Trucks' %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to **map.resources** as an alias ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cleaner way to do it, but **Search is still broken** under a specific supplier:

```
# Show all vehicles
map.connect '/vehicles/supplier/:supplier', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index
map.resources :vehicles

# Only show trucks
map.connect '/trucks/supplier/:supplier', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true
map.resources :vehicles, :as => 'trucks', :requirements => { :is_truck => true }
```

Resource: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html

Answer (score 1):

Just amend your routes in the following way:

```
map.resources :vehicles, :has_many => :suppliers,
                         :collection => { :trucks => :get }
```

And check `rake routes` for the routes this generates. It will allow you to list vehicles which are trucks:

```
trucks_vehicles GET /vehicles/trucks(.:format)
                    {:controller=>"vehicles", :action=>"trucks"}
```

So you now just need to add a new action called "trucks" which works similar to "index". Forms should keep track on it's own (via form fields) if you create a truck or another vehicle. Don't try to trick around with rails routing, which usually would mean your app design is flawed which will get you into trouble later.

You may take a look at STI (single table inheritance: one table stores multiple classes of vehicles). Another way would be to create a trucks controller which inherits from the vehicles controllers and overwrites just some methods like so:

```
class TrucksController < VehiclesController
  def new
    @is_truck = true
    super
  end
  ...
end
```

or

```
class TrucksController < VehiclesController
  before_filter :this_is_a_truck
  ...

  private

  def this_is_a_truck
    @is_truck = true
    super
  end
end
```

**Update:** Here's another one (given you have a is_truck column):

```
class TrucksController < VehiclesController
  around_filter :with_truck_scope
  ...

  private

  # Scope every active record access with an is_truck condition
  # you may want to put this directly into the model to get rid of the .send
  # method and directly access "Vehicle.with_truck_scope &block" here
  def with_truck_scope(&block)
    Vehicle.send :with_scope, :find => { :conditions => "is_truck = 1" },
                              :create => { :is_truck => 1 }, &block
  end
end
```

But I recommend really first to try out going with the `:collection` and `:member` parameters of Rails' routing.

Comment: I liked the trucks_controller.rb way. In that way, could I just map.resources :trucks ?

Comment: Going the STI way you could define "class Truck < Vehicle; end" and use the before filter to set "@Vehicle = Truck" and in the vehicles controller you do "@Vehicle.find..." instead of "Vehicle.find..." (given your VehicleController sets "@Vehicle = Vehicle" first)

Comment: STI seems the most rail-ish and cleaner way, I'll give it a try http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

Comment: STI doesn't seems to play well with Thinking_Sphinx plugin, also it seems a little bit complicated for larger applications

Answer (score 0):

are you processing it in your controller?

smth like:

```
class VehiclesController
   def index
     if params[:supplier]
       @vehicles = Vehicle.all :conditions => { :supplier_id => params[:supplier] }
     else
       @vehicles = Vehicle.all
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, a little bit different because I'm using Thinking_Sphinx, but it's the same principle

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to make an alias but at least you can try to swap your routes:

```
map.trucks '/trucks/by_supplier/:supplier', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true
map.trucks '/trucks', :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true
```

Since routes works like 'first added - has higher priority' your solution could fail since map.trucks '/trucks' catch '/trucks/by_supplier/:supplier' as well. Also I'd recommed to refactor it a bit:

```
map.with_options :controller => :vehicles, :action => :index, :is_truck => true do |v|
  v.trucks '/trucks/by_supplier/:supplier'
  v.trucks '/trucks'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use another resource, just adding:

```
map.resources :vehicles, :as => :trucks, :has_many => :suppliers
```

Then handle it in your controller with something like:

```
def index 
  conds = {}
  conds = { ... } if request.uri =~ /trucks/ # you can be more specific about the regexp if you need to
  @vehicles = Vehicle.all :conditions => conds      
end
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: I would like to make the filtering inside the routes, because the search in controller is the same, even if is a truck or not. Maybe a route namespace could work.